Zowe (zowe.org) uses Angular 12 - Is this component (Angular 12) stable and reliable?
Since Zowe, in particular the Desktop component is built Angular 12 we in the Zowe community want to be able to say it is reliable. I believe it is true to say there have been no CVEs or security issues and currently none are known but Angular 12 still gets flagged up in scans.
There is a particular feature of Angular 12 that 12 use, the ability to run code developed and shipped independently yet in a browser. If we are forced to upgrade we loose this capability (I think).
Thanks in advance for your wise words
It works perfectly today.
